# How to troubleshoot the error 'A cycle occurred while laying out the GUI'?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui, .net-maui

I am exploring MAUI RC on Windows using Visual Studio 2022 17.2 Preview and I keep getting what seems to be an random / inconsistent error:

```
A cycle occurred while laying out the GUI: Layout cycle detected.  Layout could not complete.
```

[image: Cycle exception]

Here is the XAML from the main XAML page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Sys.GatewaySimulator.Views.MainPage"
             xmlns:templates="clr-namespace:Sys.GatewaySimulator.Templates"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Sys.GatewaySimulator.Views.Components"
             BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource SecondaryColor}">
    <ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
        ..
    </ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="192" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <views:DevicesView
            Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
            DevicesComponentViewModel="{Binding DevicesComponentViewModel}"
            />
        <views:PropertiesView
            Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
            DeviceViewModel="{Binding DevicesComponentViewModel.SelectedDevice}"
            />
        <views:DesiredPropertiesView
            Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
            DeviceViewModel="{Binding DevicesComponentViewModel.SelectedDevice}"
            />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

I understood from the different pieces I gathered that something could supposedly be wrong with my XAML but I have a hard time to figure it out, especially since the error is not consistent. Sometimes it appears, some other time it does not.

The exception itself does not give much information about the cycle:

[image]

[image]

The callback is minimal:

> Hilo.Sys.GatewaySimulator.dll!Hilo.Sys.GatewaySimulator.WinUI.App.InitializeComponent.AnonymousMethod__1_1(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 68  C#

**Question**

How can I troubleshoot this error to properly fix it? Is there a tool in VS I can use to find the Cycle myself? Is there any logs to activate?

Comment: Without knowing more about the exception call stack and how the XAML and code behind for your custom views (`DevicesView`, `PropertiesView` and `DesiredPropertiesView`) looks like, it's very hard to help you.

Comment: @r2d2rigo The question was intended to be a bit less specific than asking someone to look into my company's code :) The exception in itself does not give any clue about what is this cycle that has been detected and I was wondering if there was a generic approach on how to troubleshoot this issue and find the cycle... Something more efficiently than blindly commenting out pieces of code here and there :P

Comment: @r2d2rigo That being said, I will add the exception's callstack :)

Comment: Never try to make a question "less specific". Instead, when faced with a mysterious bug, reduce the code to the minimum that causes the bug to occur. Yes, this requires "blindly commenting out pieces of code", but its the only way you - or anyone else - can isolate what causes the problem. Or you do what r2d2rigo said - provide complete information plus all the code :)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Since the exception & callback do not provide any information (like at all), the question here is about the approach to troubleshoot this kind of XAML / MAUI error :) No matter what the XAML is, how am I supposed to detect such Cycle? Is there a tool in VS? Specific logs to activate?

Comment: Ok, now that you've shown the callstack is not useful, this is a good question! Unfortunately, I'm not seeing documentation of any way to turn on additional logging of Maui internals. (I looked for xamarin.forms also.) Override `OnMeasure` of each of your views that is used on that page. In `MainPage`, override `OnMeasure`, and also `LayoutChildren` and `OnChildMeasureInvalidated`. Each of those should call its `base` method (the default code you get if you start typing  `override SomeMethodName, then `Tab`). Put WriteLine in each. Put Breakpoints to try to catch the cycle, see call stack.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I think that is great debugging device.  Now every one of my pages has  a cycle detected in it at run-time at some sizes.    I can't seem to override OnMeasure on my settings page, it's not a member of ContentPage...